# how to create join between two ordered table and save the order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to join between 2 tables , every table is ordered and I need to save this order , but to return only one table.
let say that I have table order from a to z
and second table order a to z
and I want to create
single table ordered like that:

[image]

how can I do that?
AM I need to create temporare table?

Comment: I would prolly look into using rank or denserank plus a union. Seems pretty straight forward to me :)

Comment: What do you mean by the tables being "ordered"? There's no concept of "order" in a SQL database unless you provide a column that contains the order sequence. Regardless of the order that rows are created, SQL can return them in any order unless you include an `ORDER BY` clause in the query.

Comment: i mean that i need to return single table that join 2 tables (ordered each own)
and save the order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "ordered table".  In SQL, tables represent *unordered* sets.  Period.

If you want the union of two tables ordered in the result set, you need to use `order by`.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*  -- you might want to list the columns and remove `which`
from ((select t1.*, 1 as which from table1
      ) union all
      (select t2.*, 2 as which from table2
      )
     ) t
order by which,
         (case when which = 1 then t1.<ordering column> end),
         (case when which = 2 then t2.<ordering column> end)
```

Note that this uses separate `case` expressions for ordering the two tables.  This allows different types for the ordering column(s) in the two tables.

Comment: I don't think case statement is required. `Order by which,ordering column` is enough

Comment: @KumarHarsh . . . The question wasn't clear if the ordering was based on the same column for both tables.

Comment: the command that help me was Union all , it really different from union only